# Minimal values of X and Y coordinates in PointCollection (C#)

Tags: c#, coordinates, max, point, minimum

let's assume I have got a collection of points (`PointCollection`).
What I want to do is to find the minimal value of X and Y coordinates among these points.
Obviously one could iterate over the collection and check the coordinates step by step.

I wonder if there is a quicker and more efficient solution.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: So you want two points ? The one with the lowest X and the one with the lowest Y, or one point with the lowest combined X and Y?

Comment: Unless they are already sorted, there's nothing quicker than examining them all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quicker to type?  Perhaps:

```
var xMin = points.Min(p => p.X);
var yMin = points.Min(p => p.Y);
```

But that will *execute* slower than a single `foreach` loop:

```
bool first = true;
foreach(var point in points) {
    if(first) {
        xMin = point.X;
        yMin = point.Y;
        first = false;
    } else {
        if(point.X < xMin) xMin = point.X;
        if(point.Y < yMin) yMin = point.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for the fastest solution. Why did you assume that the first one will be slower?

Comment: also this code is checking a none necessary if every time, just assign xmin and ymin to int.MaxValue, then use foreach and the body is just the else block

Comment: @HPT - OK, that it quite a nice addition. @Jamie - because a: it loops twice rather than once, and b: LINQ works on the least-common denominator approach - it can't use any custom iterator defined for the collection type, and has to do additional delegate-invokes.

Answer (score 3):

To get the lowest x and y positions seperately, use

```
var lowestX = pointCollection.Min( p => p.X );
var lowestY = pointCollection.Min( p => p.Y );
```

If you want the one with the lowest combined X and Y position, use

```
var lowest = pointCollection.Min( p => p.X + p.Y );
```